# Bootstrap sticky navbar disappears on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a single page website using Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.5. I have a navbar-fixed-top in the website which works fine and does the job but the problem I am facing is, whenever I reload/refresh page from the middle, fixed/sticky navbar doesn't show unless I scroll. Can someone help me solving the problem?

Link to the site is http://www.shahpoojan.com/vs

You can click on reel or bio and then refresh browser. I am using firefox to test it.

Waiting for a response. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the normal behaviour the page expects a `scroll` event to add a class of fixed to the navbar, you can make the navbar `fixed` from the start if you really wanted to change that.

Comment: Thanks mate. I think I will stick with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

You must have some sort of javascript code adding classes to the nav for the fade effect try replacing the nav classes

from this `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top id="nav">`

to this `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-fixed-top" id="nav">`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I changed to what you said but the navbar-fixed will only appear after caffeinated link (i.e. from reels div). Also I put e.preventDefault() in scroll javascript but it stays active when I scroll after clicking a link.

I have updated the link, you can check www.shahpoojan.com/vs